# How to deal with multiple ids multiple categories table to reach THIS on Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have a problem that i was trying to solve 3 days ago and i'm not able to.

I have the following tables:

Companies

| company_id | sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 |
| 2 | 3000 |
| 3 | 4000 |
| 4 | 1000 |

Categories

| company_id | category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | medical |
| 1 | sports |
| 2 | industrial |
| 3 | consumption |
| 4 | medical |
| 4 | consumption |

All i want to reach is a COLUMN CHART with a CATEGORY SLICER where i choose the category and i see the TOP 5 companies by category and sales. Yes, in this example the TOP is not needed but in my real case i have 400 companies so i want to:

1. Select and Show only the required category.
2. In that category, show only the 5 better companies by sales.

The problem here is Power BI takes all the companies for the TOP N filter so if i choose a category, and also try a top 5, if the companies are not in the TOP5 all companies list, it doesn`t show anything.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the filter pane and select Top N (Or translated from dutch 'Popular N') for the MAX(Value). 

This way, if you use a slicer, it will show the top 5 for the category you have selected.

Comment: Hi Max. Which variable on my filter panel (id, sales, category) should i apply the TOP N Max(Value) to? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to see the 5 highest (or lowest) sales, you should select sales. :)

Comment: I applied a TOP 5 Filter to the id field, selecting Max(Sales) and nothing happened. I also applied a TOP 5 Filter to the category field, selecting Max(Sales) and nothing happened too. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to show the same Top N values in your visual, you can use the filter pane to achieve that.

Below a walk through:

[image: Initial setup]

The to add the Top N filtering, I add the following:

[image: Filter]

It is in Dutch, so a little clarification:

- I add a 'filter on this visual'
- I selected Populairste N, which is Top N
- And as a value I drag and dropped the maximum of sales.

Results:

[image: Unfiltered result][image: Filtered result]

Things to keep in mind:

- You are using a many to many relationship, make sure that this is activated in the Power BI model.
- Make sure the direction of filtering is from category to sales, otherwise the slicer will not work. It looks like this:

[image: Power BI Model]

Comment: This is not a good solution for me because your VK1 field is Unique. My company_id field is not unique. If i only have 1 company_id in the categories table this would be so easy, but it's not my case...

Comment: VK1 is not unique. It is added for every conversation that is held for that specific sales organization. For example code 401 is found 28000 times within the fact table. 

As a slicer however, powerbi only shows all unique values.

Comment: RaxGG, I've edited my answer to include your test-data. I also added in the data model since I think that it might go wrong there. Hopefully it helps!

Comment: Dude, sorry for responding this late but you saved my life there, it was exactly what i was looking for and my fault was the direction of the filtering... You have a beer for free assured when i travel to Germany! :)

Comment: I live in the Netherlands though :'(
You're welcome!